# Pass param to a silverlight application

Tags: c#, jquery, silverlight

In my javascript I create my `<OBJECT>` tag

```
                var htmlEmbedSilverlight = "<div id='silverlightControlHost'> "
                        + "<object data='data:application/x-silverlight-2,' type='application/x-silverlight-2' width='550px' height='250px'> "
                        + "<param name='source' value='../../ClientBin/FotoEmprestimoChave.xap'/> "
                        + "<param name='onError' value='onSilverlightError' /> "
                        + "<param name='background' value='white' /> "
                        + "<param name='minRuntimeVersion' value='4.0.60310.0' /> "
                        + "<param name='autoUpgrade' value='true' /> "
                        + "<param name='initparams' values='chave_id=" + data + "' /> "
                        + "<a href='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0' style='text-decoration:none'> "
                        + "<img src='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376' alt='Get Microsoft Silverlight' style='border-style:none'/> "
                        + "</a> "
                        + "</object><iframe id='_sl_historyFrame' style='visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px'></iframe></div>";
                $("#tiraFotoSilverlight").html(htmlEmbedSilverlight);
```

This is a reference to my Silverlight application where I call in my Web Application. The problem is my `<param name='initparams' values='chave_id=" + data + "' /> "` because in my `App.xaml` in Silverlight, I have the code below

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.InitParams != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.InitParams)
                {
                    this.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();            
        }
```

Where `InitParams` always has Count = 0 and I don't know why. Can someone help me ? I'm just trying to pass a value to my Silverlight application, without a `PostBack`.

**Rendered**

```
    <object width="550px" height="250px" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,">
    <param value="../../ClientBin/FotoEmprestimoChave.xap" name="source">
    <param value="onSilverlightError" name="onError">
    <param value="white" name="background">
    <param value="4.0.60310.0" name="minRuntimeVersion">
    <param value="true" name="autoUpgrade">
    <param values="chave_id=1" name="initparams">
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0">
</object>
```

Comment: What value is `data` in this case? Can you double-check the final rendered HTML code in your page?

Comment: I've tryied to pass a static value like `value='chave_id=1'` but without success

Comment: `data` will return the `id` of a insert in my database.

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you wire the event in Silverlight? In addition, can you post the _actual rendered HTML_ in the page as a result of that JavaScript call?

Comment: I try to get the `param` in my `Application_Startup` event, like I posted, with the `e.InitParams`. I updated my question with the rendered page.

Comment: I see it now, you're using plural `values` instead of singular `value`. Easy enough to miss and if I had a nickel for every time something like that happened to me... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong key/value pair for the `param` tag for `initparams`. You're using `<param values=` when it should be `<param value=` (notice singular "value" vs plural "values")

Change your JavaScript line to:

`+ "<param name='initparams' value='chave_id=" + data + "' /> "`